# Update attribute of Post model with tags each time they are created or saved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have *Post* model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :content, :tag_list 

  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
end
```

and a *Tag* model:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
  end
end
```

As you can see they have a `has_and belongs_to_many` association with each other and I also created a joint table:

```
create_table :posts_tags, :id => false do | t |
  t.integer :post_id, :tag_id
end
```

I want to do the following:

Each time a post's tag(s) are created or saved the `tag_list` attribute of the post that the tags belong to should update with the tags.

Any suggestions to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest adding an `after_save` callback to Tag model.

```
after_save :update_tag_list_on_posts

private
  def update_tag_list_on_posts
    posts.update_all(:tag_list => desired_tag_list_value)   
  end
```

Comment: I did not get what tag_list serves for a post. That is why I placed `desired_tag_list_value` for update. Can you elaborate more on this ?

Comment: thanks for replying. tag_list stores each tag that belongs to the post. When a post is saved the tags in the

Comment: input field are saved in tag_list

Comment: "tag_list stores each tag that belongs to the post". If so, then why have a separate tag_list ? In order to access all tags that belongs to a post, we can simply call `.tags` on the post object as they have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association with each other. Is there something more that I did not get about having tag_list in Post model ?

Comment: Sorry I had my Internet connection suffered some problems last night so I couldn't tick the answer.